# Relationship between mN and mg in vessel contraction studies?

Tags: physiology, blood-circulation

What is the relationship between **mN** and **mg** as the units involved to measure the changes in contraction?  A tool most widely used is an instrument called myograph. In these exoeriments, either units of **mg** or **mN** is used without any mention of why. Note that the first two examples use an experimental tool called a **myograph** - used to measure the force produced by a muscle (in this case muscular blood vessels) when under contraction. Both examples mention tension. Wether these myograph experiments are completely different i'm unsure.

1. **This example shows force as 'mN' from [this paper Fig 1A a](http://ajplung.physiology.org/content/293/4/L982).**
   Those who are interested the caption is as follows
   *"Effects of Li+-PSS and NMDG-PSS in PGF2α-preconstricted pulmonary arteries. Intrapulmonary arteries (IPA) were first exposed to 80 mM K+, and endothelial function was assessed by relaxation of PGF2α contractions (10 μM) to acetylcholine (10 μM). Following a period of recovery, IPA were preconstricted to 10–15% 80K using PGF2α, and then physiological saline solution (PSS) was replaced by Li+-PSS in the continuing presence of the same concentration of PGF2α in endothelium-intact IPA"*
   [image]
2. **This example shows units as 'g'. note that some examples from other papers also use units of mg essentiall x1000 similar to other unit conversions** from
   [this paper Fig 1a](http://ajpcell.physiology.org/content/302/1/C307).
   The caption is pretty much the same as 1. Particularly thromboxane A2 (TXA2) is a pharmacological agent affecting a set of ion channels:
   *"Requirement of thromboxane A2 (TXA2) for hypoxic pulmonary vasoconstriction (HPV) in rat pulmonary arteries (PAs). A: hypoxia alone (3% PO2) did not **induce contraction of PA (left)**. In the presence of 10 nM U46619, hypoxia **induced a strong contraction** equivalent with the response to high K+ (80K, right)"*
   [image]
3. For a third example [click here](http://www.medsci.org/v10p0771.htm). It does interestingly state *"The PA rings were stretched to a predetermined optimal passive tension of **750 mg**"*. As such mg (or g) is an alternative representation of a unit of force as presumed. Figure 1 in this link again demonstrates mg as an y-axis unit of measurement under myograph experiment

Comment: `1kg weight = 9.8 N` but I am not sure if that is what they mean here.

Comment: Ick, unlabeled axes. Do you have a description of the figure from the text? Something like 'In figure A we describe...' would help a lot. g doesn't seem like a unit of force, but I'm not sure what else they could be measuring. Perhaps it's literally a gram weight?

Comment: @woosah: Can you post a little bit bigger (2nd) picture?

Comment: @DevashishDas
I added some more examples and made images bigger. Plus links to articles

Comment: @JeremyKemball I added some more notes and caption and also links to articles. If you think I should write more on this question let me know I'll change it

Comment: @WYSIWYG May be you're onto something. As mentioned above which i noticed in example 3: _"The PA rings were stretched to a predetermined optimal passive tension of 750 mg"_. Clearly its a unit of force. 750mg is approximately 7350 mN? That sounds too big here though if my calculation are correct. As you said don't know what they mean, seems unusual to use that formula anyway

Comment: Something looks off. $1^{st}$ is N/m or Tension or unit force exerted on the artery walls. Whereas $2^{nd}$ one is actually change in mass of thromboxane $A_2$ ($TXA_2$) with time. Can you clarify that?

Comment: @DevashishDas I wouldn't even know fully but that force represented in the graphs are 'resultant' forces ins response to various stimulus'. The 2nd graph is also change in contraction from a myograph experiment (I included some caption). Thromboxane A2 (TXA2) is just a pharmacological agent used in some experiments to affect certain channels. TXA2 is an example of a stimulus during a typical myograph experiment along with introducing hypoxia or change in ionic concentrations (e.g. 80K+ Fig 2 in question).

Comment: @DevashishDas Maybe there are different myograph experiments hence different units due to different types of contractile force. I just found out there  are several set ups of a myograph whose sole aim is to measure contraction in pieces of muscle (in my case pertaining to blood vessels but apply to anything muscular).

Two types of experiments I just come across are wire and pressure myographs

Answer (score 1):

The difference between above two units is a matter of metric systems used:
The newton (symbol: N) is the International System of Units (SI) derived unit of force. One newton is the force needed to accelerate one kilogram of mass at the rate of one metre per second squared.

Another system:  kilogram (gram, milligram)-force
The kilogram-force (kgf or kgF) is a gravitational metric unit of force. It is equal to the magnitude of the force exerted by one kilogram of mass in a 9.80665 m/s2 gravitational field (standard gravity, a conventional value approximating the average magnitude of gravity on Earth). Therefore one kilogram-force is by definition equal to 9.80665 N. Similarly, a gram-force is 9.80665 mN, and a milligram-force is 9.80665 µN. 
Kilogram-force is a non-standard unit and does not comply with the SI Metric System.
See:
http://www.sengpielaudio.com/ConvForce.htm